# How to turn invaild json into vaild json?

Tags: jquery, json

Im trying to read a json file in jQuery that has 300 products but it isnt working because its not vaild json. It currently looks like this for every product in the file. This is just an example with 2 products.

```
{ "products": [
{"asin": "B0002FHIWQ", "title": "Hanes Unisex Beefy-T 100% Cotton Long 
Sleeve T-Shirt", "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-
amazon.com/images/I/41tQBha0m3L._SY445_.jpg", "related": 
{"also_bought": ["B0002FHIMQ", "B0002FHIM6", "B000M9N0LA"], 
"also_viewed": ["B00147ZMWY", "B0002FHIMQ", "B000VSHUNG", "B003EZHGYQ", 
"B003EZJHOI", "B006WOD4DS", "B0049A9FVW", "B001MB5KS8", "B000PFL6Y4", 
"B00BBQG09M", "B0006TSYZI", "B003AU5WJQ", "B0002X4HTK", "B000BUVLIE", 
"B006ZS8Y54", "B000ID194A", "B004BH0GRK", "B0012N37TA", "B00KUL3NOO", 
"B00KUL34WU", "B00BBWBNFC", "B001B2JIMC", "B0071NMHDC", "B004ZBM5KS", 
"B00BDBEQJ6", "B003IXBEX8", "B003UWAIT8", "B00H32OK86", "B000KBCQ74", 
"B0012N84G6", "B003TPBRBY", "B002UZ3S9S", "B001KL7GJG", "B003UWF6P4", 
"B008ER1JP6", "B006ZS9C1O", "B004ZBM5OY", "B0013EIEE6", "B003UWC6AC", 
"B005Z1TOD8", "B006Z8FRAO", "B004R1ENGU", "B00EOZGC7W", "B002YRV3W6", 
"B007C39WIE", "B00H32OEQE", "B000CBV8PS", "B0012N84DY", "B00266PCMW", 
"B00AOO14HA", "B00BF3WYQE", "B00BBQ9PGM", "B002G9U8VE", "B0002VNLC6", 
"B00AYYXW3E", "B0002FHIVM"], "bought_together": ["B00147ZMWY", 
"B0049A9FVW", "B000VSHUNG"]}, "salesRank": {"Clothing": 6992}, 
"categories": [["Sports & Outdoors", "Clothing", "Men", "Shirts", "T-
Shirts"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Clothing", "Shirts", 
"T-Shirts"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Big & Tall"]]}
{"asin": "B0002FHIM6", "title": "Fruit of the Loom 5.4 oz.Cotton T-
Shirt", "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-
amazon.com/images/I/41oKghMoCML._SY445_.jpg", "related": 
{"also_bought": ["B0002FHIMQ", "B000KK2O5Y"], "also_viewed": 
["B0007IBYO6", "B0050AFWTO", "B0002FHIVM", "B00079WDZ4", "B00B81I4IU", 
"B0002FHIXK", "B000BTIKQQ", "B00DOFXPSM", "B00B81I4HQ", "B00AZ70UBW", 
"B000P50YLK", "B000BVGLTM", "B003YQLC6I", "B0013EIS88", "B00AZ6Z1DA", 
"B003IX3EWC", "B00ACIFB5O", "B000BY41FK", "B000853HJI", "B000P57EUE", 
"B000ICX36I", "B0010EG85Q", "B00CIZH8X2", "B00AYYXW3E", "B00HZ31A2C", 
"B0002FHILW", "B00LP8LUIW", "B0002FHINA", "B00CMP7R02", "B0071NMH9G", 
"B00BF400TG", "B0012NBP58", "B00H32BZLQ", "B001RTSCUI", "B00CMP60J6", 
"B001T3UBVA", "B000CBV8PS", "B00BEO1Y1U", "B0014JFFZ6", "B00G6N8ONU", 
"B0012N37OA", "B00A7QU8ZY", "B0014C5490", "B00CMP5RTK", "B0049A9FVW", 
"B005LLP0LM", "B000BWI0AO", "B00ACIF9WE", "B005CW054C", "B0002FHIMQ", 
"B003TP8HJ4", "B0012F5U3E"], "bought_together": ["B0002FHIVM", 
"B00079WDZ4"]}, "salesRank": {"Clothing": 31}, "categories": [["Sports 
& Outdoors", "Clothing"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", 
"Clothing", "Shirts", "T-Shirts"]]}
]}
```

Which is not vaild json I have made it look this for the first product but the file has just over 300 products so there must be an easier then to do it all manually?

```
{ "products": [
    {
 "asin": "B0001MQ60A",
 "title": "KEEN Men's Newport H2 Sandal",
 "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pRaO7fFSL._SX395_.jpg",
 "related": {"also_bought": ["B000MN8OR6"],
   "also_viewed": ["B0000DYKET", "B0035FE60M", "B008KI85R4", "B000MQWVA4", "B003Z4KHXS", "B00GUBOCGQ",
     "B003O2SLXY", "B0017KSRMA", "B003O2SBKM", "B00DSN637U", "B000HDJ8IK", "B00E0J3HVG", "B003Z4KGZW",
     "B005HO2CYG", "B003H4QFVY", "B0017LB2VC", "B002R8JPTK", "B008KI84SE", "B005DJDL9A", "B003TU14OE",
     "B00E0J3HTI", "B000EDTVYY", "B003Z4JOJG", "B00DSN638E", "B00E0J3HVQ", "B008KI88JY", "B00EZIRE20",
     "B0095RGEH2", "B00CEX6MSU", "B000B84URK", "B003O2SPMG", "B002KKCWP4", "B003O2SLXE", "B00JQHFV0M",
     "B008JE8V14", "B0055ATVDW", "B003Z4KLMA", "B008ZAY40Y", "B003H4QFV4", "B00DSN64BU", "B002KKCZLA",
     "B0055ATVV4", "B00HFY47JY", "B00DPHJUTW", "B008FWRJ6I", "B003Z4JUFO", "B00JFB4RL8", "B00HR1LTNM",
     "B005HMTPBG", "B00KCT84I4", "B00HXDITEG"],
     "bought_together": ["B003O2SLXY", "B003H4QFVY", "B002R8JPTK", "B000EDTVYY"]},
     "salesRank": {"Shoes": 18},
     "categories": [["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Shoes & Accessories: International Shipping Available"],
     ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "K", "Keen"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Comfort Shoes"],
     ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Sandals"],
     ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Athletic", "Sport Sandals"]]} 
]}
```

Also, I think the problem with it not being vaild json it at the end of every product it doesn't have a comma after the curly bracket like so '},' is that the only reason or can anyone see another?

Comment: What is the original source? Note the second version passes validation

Comment: got the dataset from amazon

Comment: Something wrong then in how you are putting it into the file. Get it from amazon how?

Comment: http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/

Comment: I suppose you dumped the responses from several queries into that single file. If so, that is what you should *not* do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it, I used Atoms find and replace feature and replaced all `]]}` with `]}},` no coding needed :)

Answer (score -2):

I put your two example products into a file called `data.json` and then created a python3 script `fixjson.py` next to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json 
import pprint

with open("data.json", "r") as f:

    data = ""
    for line in f.readlines():
        data += line.strip()

    data = data.replace("}{\"asin", "},{\"asin")
    products = json.loads(data)
    pprint.pprint(products)

with open("newdata.json", "w") as w:
    w.write(json.dumps(products, indent=2))
```

Run the script with `python3 fixjson.py`. It should fix your broken JSON by inserting the missing `,` between the products and write the data with an intendation level of 2 to a file called `newdata.json`.

Note: This is just a quick&dirty approach.

Edit: Why am I getting downvoted? OP asked for a better way than manually fixing the file and I provided a snippet that should fix the JSON issue based on the given information.